# Update MC to 1.9

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, hosting

So, I updated my PC Minecraft to 1.9. Here's my problem. I mainly use MC for servers so I can connect with my friends overseas. All the servers I use are now outdated, and I now have no contact with my overseas friends. Do I manually update these or does the server owner have to do that? Please help me because MC is my life right now, and my online friends have got me through a lot of problems. 
Thanks xxx
EDIT: Thanks for your help guys, I am on Hypixel right now, as that was the only one that is 1.8 and 1.9 compatible, I am also in contact with my overseas friends through Enjin. Thanks for all your help guys! x

Comment: I would suggest getting something like a Raidcall server or something so that you can contact them outside of the game.

Comment: If you think someone answered your question, please do click the green check to mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 1):

Updating the servers has to be done by the server owners manually. Until they do, your game will show the servers as outdated in your multiplayer menu. Note that Minecraft Realms are automatically updated by Mojang to the latest release. There is nothing you have to do to upgrade a realm.

Another thing to note is that unlike most modern games, you can always choose to play an older version of the game by choosing one in the profile editor of the Launcher.

To do so, open the Launcher and click on <kbd>Edit Profile</kbd> in the lower left corner. Under *Version Selection* there's a dropdown box labeled *Use Version*. Choose the version for your servers from that list and start the game to play with your friends.

You can also make a different profile for each version you play, for quick access.

Final word of warning: Be careful to not open worlds you played in 1.9 in 1.8, as it might break things.

Answer (score 0):

The person who's in charge of the server must update them. 1.9 is fairly new so I'd give them a while to do so.

Remember that you can still play on 1.8.x servers by changing your version in the "Edit Profile" Section

Comment: Oh, MrLemon beat me to it!